# What's the real resolution for a recent Macbook Pro FaceTime HD Camera?

Tags: javascript, camera, webrtc, macbookpro

Apple website states that it's capable of FullHD that's 1920x1080. Interesting fact that when I capture a stream like this:

```js
const s = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 1080, height: 1920 } });
```

it'll have larger FOV than when it's landscape-oriented.
Another thing that's available in Chromium-like browsers is `getPhoto()` API, and for it (https://simpl.info/imagecapture/ or https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html ) it shows image of 1552x1552 that's a bit narrower for FOV than FHD frame, but much higher and has bigger vertical FOV.

I can conclude physical image sensor is at least 1920x1552 px. Does anyone know exact dimensions or has a link to a datasheet for the camera module that's used in those Macs?

I tried to find some data on Internet but haven't succeeded so far.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [apple.se] would be a better place for questions like this.

Comment: chrome://media-internals will show details of the underlying hardware after you used getUserMedia. That is not available to JS for fingerprinting reasons but may help in your case.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke that really helped, I see "1552x1552" there as well as couple more strange resolutions.